# how to access value of cfset into ajax function

Tags: coldfusion

I am new in ColdFusion.
I am trying to access ColdFusion value into ajax function.

```
<cfset lagtime=#data# />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
 function test(){
   var adata =<cfoutput>#lagtime#</cfoutput>;
   alert(adata);
 }
</script>
```

I want to access `lagtime` value into variable `adata`.
If anyone know please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: in your JS you have a var called `adata` and then an alert of `data` which should be `adata`. I'm guessing in your JS console that you will see an error message which will help you diagnose issues. Also is `lagtime` a numeric value?

Comment: thanks for reply john. It was my fault , yes in js it should be adata and lagtime is a numeric value.

Comment: You are also missing a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for reply Dan i have tried that but still its not working

Comment: `<cfset lagtime=#data# />` you don't need to use pound symbols in this case. ie `<cfset lagtime = data />`. The what is wrong is that if the value of variable `lagtime` is a simple string, the resultant script will look like ` var adata = lagtimevalue;`

Comment: *still its not working* Can you elaborate? What exactly is it doing wrong.  The example above works fine with `<cfset lagtime=123/>` assuming you invoke the `test();` function somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you may be running into is that the value contained inside your data parameter could be a string causing your javascript to break. Just in case I have wrapped the output in single quotes which tells javascript to treat your value as a string.

Also I am not sure what your HTML looks like. For completeness I have include a full working example. Also note that the lagtime variable is not really required.

```
<cfset data = "hello">

<cfoutput>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function test()
    {
        var adata = '#data#';
        alert(adata);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Execute Test" onclick="test();">
    </body>
</html>
</cfoutput>
```

Also to be clear you are not accessing the coldfusion variable. What you are doing is creating the javascript dynamically using coldfusion. e.g. Thats why could can not assign a javascript variable to a coldfusion variable inside a cfml template.

Comment: Hi Scherzer, Thanks for reply .I am accepting hello in alert but its giving  #data#.

Comment: Sounds like you omitted the `cfoutput` from your code.  Did you try the example above *exactly as is*?  That said, technically you do not need quotes for numeric values. However, you should really use [JSStringFormat](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/JSStringFormat) to ensure any special characters that might occur within the value are properly escaped for javascript.

Comment: *RE: lagtime is a numeric value* @user3090158 - Assuming a numeric value, there was nothing obviously wrong with your example other than the fact that you are not actually invoking the function anywhere. So please explain *how* it is not working.  What are the actual results? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: are you sure your file has ending with .cfm or .cfml because from what you are describing in your comment coldfusion is not processing your page.

Comment: Also, since you mentioned being new to CF are you able to run *any* CF code. For example, if you create a simple .cfm file that just displays the current time, does it work?   `<cfoutput>now() = #now()#</cfoutput>`

Answer (score 0):

If the data type is `string` then use:

```
var adata = "<cfoutput>#lagtime#</cfoutput>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage using [`toScript()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ToScript) function to assign a ColdFusion variable to Javascript. It also supports conversion of complex data types such as Array, Structure and Query.

```
<cfset lagtime=#data# />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<cfoutput>
 function test(){
   var #toScript(lagtime, "adata")#;
   alert(adata);
 }
</cfoutput>
</script>
```

To be clear, it does the same thing as dynamically declaring a javascript variable, but it takes out the worry of type matching and notation. You can forget about the notation and concentrate on your data. Imagine the pain, if this variable was a `query` or an `array` object.